# Ajax Request on Redirected Site

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I just cannot get my ajax request working on my redirected site `input-city.php`. Here is the entry for the mod-rewrite in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^test-(bonn)/$ /input-city.php?city=$1 [NC,L]
```

I already copied and tested the ajax request on other pages and it worked like a charm, but here it just reloads the page, I just cannot get my head wrapped around it. The ajax request should just load in some content into the div when the link is being clicked.

The ajax request on my `input-city.php` (with the script link below):

```
<div id="addsubject5"><a href="https://xxx/test-bonn/" id="addsubjectlink5" data-target="/partials/addchoosesubject5">test</span></a></d‌​iv>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The entry for that ajax request in my `global.js`:

```
$(function() {
var trigger = $('#addsubjectlink5'),
container = $('#addsubject5');

trigger.on('click', function() {
   var $this = $(this),
    target = $this.data('target');

    container.load(target + '.php');
    return false;

});
});
```

And to make it complete, my `addchoosesubject5.php`:

```
<p>test</p>
```

Or is it just not possible to do ajax requests on redirected pages? When I search for it I only get results for "redirect page after ajax request", so this didn't help much :/.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the Javascript being loaded on the site where you want to use it?

Comment: You have a problem with your relative path. Easiest fix: Make it relative to the web root, by starting it with a slash.

Comment: @TobiasF.: Yes, the script is loaded on the page `input-city.php` where the ajax request is sent and where the div should be filled with the content.

Comment: @CBroe: I have now changed the ajax request on `input-city.php`to: `<div id="addsubject5"><a href="https://xxx/test-bonn/" id="addsubjectlink5" data-target="/partials/addchoosesubject5">test</span></a></div>` but still not working - just a page reload :/. I only got suspicious that it is about the redirected page because the exact same ajax request works on other pages.

Comment: It makes no sense that an AJAX request would “reload” the page - it is not even _capable_ of that by itself, because it is a _background_ request. Have you checked the browser console for errors? And also the network panel to see what request is made (if any)?

Comment: @CBroe I now used the console and it gave me a 404 error - `https://xxx/test-bonn/js/global.js` not found. So the relative path of the script was the problem. Sorry for the circumstances, somehow still forgot about the console. I will make a mental note for that. Thank you big time for still helping me here!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CBroe: The problem was the relative path from the script `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Since the page is redirected to a folder path `/test-bonn/` in the `.htaccess` I needed to adapt the path, because the relative path led to `/test-bonn/js/global.js` compared to all other pages that are not redirected. I simply inserted an absolute path and the problem got solved.